# Swift ios: is there a way to always have collectionview (not cell) height =width?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a custom collectionview with cells that auto adjust to its width, but for some reason its height cuts the cells short so I got to scroll....I am trying to use auto layout for this but it does't work for me, I can't figure it out.

I have 3 labels under the collectionView.

I did have a constraint for margin in relation to the super view which stretched the width of the collection view even though I set it to greater or equal to 0.
When I set it off height = width but I'd like it to stretch so it supports other device sizes ....I need the height to stretch as well though, which does not happen, no matter what I tried, height keeps turning out smaller than width.

This is the code for the collectionview

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  collectionview_xmixdrix
//
//  Created by admin on 3/4/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 il.ac.afeka. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource
{

var pictures:[String] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
var visibleCells:[String]=[]
var numInactiveCards=0
var numSections = 0
var numCols = 0
 var timer = NSTimer()
var counter=0

let delay_t = 0.5
let TileMargin = CGFloat(10.0)


@IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ScoreInputLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var UIcv: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var WinningLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad()

{
    super.viewDidLoad()

   // self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=false
    pictures+=pictures
    numCols=Int(sqrt(Float(pictures.count)))
    numSections=numCols

    playbutton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func timerAction()
{
    counter+=1
    ScoreInputLabel.text = "\(counter)"
}

@IBAction func playAndReset(sender: AnyObject)
{
    ScoreInputLabel.text="0"
    WinningLabel.hidden=true
    gameInit()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    playbutton.hidden=true
}


func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->())
{
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return numCols
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numSections
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellidentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
          return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let rowsCount = CGFloat(numCols)
    let totalTileMargin = TileMargin * (rowsCount + 1)
     let dimentions = (collectionView.frame.width-totalTileMargin) / (rowsCount )
 //   let dimentions = collectionView.frame.width / rowsCount - (rowsCount * TileMargin )

    return CGSize(width: dimentions, height: dimentions) // collectionView.frame.height * 0.9
}
/*
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(TileMargin, TileMargin, TileMargin, TileMargin)
}
*/

func gameInit()
{
    counter=0
    var tmpPictures = pictures
    for  i in 0 ..< UIcv.numberOfSections()
    {
        for  j in 0 ..< UIcv.numberOfItemsInSection(i)
        {

            let cell=UIcv.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: j,inSection: i)) as! CollectionViewCell
            let rnd = getRandom(tmpPictures.count)

            cell.cellLabel.text="?"

            cell.initCard(tmpPictures[rnd])
            tmpPictures.removeAtIndex(rnd)
            numInactiveCards=0
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell=collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if(!cell.isFlipped && cell.isActive  )
    {
        cell.flipCard()

        self.visibleCells.append(cell.cardPicture)
        print("visiblecards: \(self.visibleCells) \n count:\( self.visibleCells.count)")

        if(self.visibleCells.count>=2)
        {
            CheckIfSuitablePair(collectionView )
             self.visibleCells.removeAll()
        }

    }

}

//checking if pair is good, if bad pair it unflips if good, checks for winning
func CheckIfSuitablePair(cv: UICollectionView)
{

    let cmpResult=compareCards(visibleCells[0], card2: self.visibleCells[1])

    for  i in 0 ..< cv.numberOfSections()
    {
        for  j in 0 ..< cv.numberOfItemsInSection(i)
        {

            let cell=cv.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: j,inSection: i)) as! CollectionViewCell


            if(cell.isActive && cell.isFlipped)
            {
                if(!cmpResult) //cards are different
                {delay(delay_t){cell.flipCard()}}

                else //cards are same
                {
                    cell.isActive=false
                    self.numInactiveCards+=1

                    if(checkWin())
                    {updateWinningLabels()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



func checkWin()->Bool
{
    if(numInactiveCards==pictures.count)
    {return true}
    return false
}

func updateWinningLabels()
{
    timer.invalidate()
    playbutton.setTitle("Play again", forState: .Normal)
    playbutton.hidden=false
    WinningLabel.hidden=false
}

func compareCards(card1:String , card2:String) -> Bool
{
    if(card1==card2)
    {return true}
    else {return false}
}

func getRandom(range: Int)->Int
{
    srand(1)
    let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range))
    return Int(random)
}
}
```

Comment: You can add a constraint to make your CollectionView proportional, aspect ratio constraint can be added with 1:1 proportion

Comment: Yea I just figured it out actually, this fixes the problem :)